# How to make columns from joined tables available in Ransack attribute field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I want to display belongs_to relationship columns in ransackable attributes list. So that I can display them in the dropdown, and perform an advanced search on the (joined) table.
How can I do that?

Below my model, where each manifest has one consignee. I've adjusted the attribute list, but when I select the consignee name it looks for 'manifest'.'name' and not in 'consignee'.'name' via a JOIN.
When I use the simple search form, it works correctly.

manifest.rb

```
class Manifest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shipper
  belongs_to :consignee
  ...
  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    super - ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'consignee_id']
    super + ['consignee_name']
  end
end
```

consignee.rb

```
class Consignee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :manifest, dependent: :destroy
    ...
end
```

manifest_controller.rb

```
...
def index
    @search = ransack_params
    @search.build_grouping unless @search.groupings.any?
    @manifests  = @search.result(distinct: true)
    @search.build_condition
...
private
    def ransack_params
        Manifest.includes(:vessel, :pod, :pol, :por, :del,  :consignee).ransack(params[:q])
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= c.attribute_fields do |a| %>
        <%= a.attribute_select %>
      <% end %>
      <%= c.predicate_select :only => [:cont, :not_cont, :matches]%>
      <%= c.value_fields do |v| %>
        <%= v.text_field :value %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

I expect to see Consignee Name in the dropdown list, but only see 'Name' at the bottom. When I select this and press search it returns with an error:

```
undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass 
on line: Manifest.includes(:vessel, :pod, :pol, :por, :del, :consignee).ransack(params[:q])
```

Answer (score 0):

manifest.rb (define `ransackable_attributes` only for this model)

```
class Manifest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shipper
  belongs_to :consignee
  ...
  private
  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    super - ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'consignee_id']
  end
end
```

consignee.rb (define `ransackable_attributes` for this model)

```
class Consignee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :manifest, dependent: :destroy
  ...
  private
  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    if auth_object == :manifest_search
      ['name']
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

manifest_controller.rb

```
...
def index
  @search = ransack_params
  @search.build_grouping unless @search.groupings.any?
  @manifests  = @search.result(distinct: true)
  @search.build_condition
...

private
def ransack_params
  Manifest.ransack(params[:q], auth_object: :manifest_search)
end
```

index.html.erb (add the associations parameter to `attribute_select`)

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= c.attribute_fields do |a| %>
        <%= a.attribute_select :associations => ["consignee"] %>
      <% end %>
      <%= c.predicate_select :only => [:cont, :not_cont, :matches]%>
      <%= c.value_fields do |v| %>
        <%= v.text_field :value %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

note that the `auth_object` conditional is optional, but it allows you to have different search pages with different attributes. For example, the consignee page could have its own search form showing all of consignee's attributes, while the manifest search shows only the consignee name as a searchable attribute.

I removed the `includes` to simplify the code; it's not required to make the search work.  If you need those associations pre-loaded, you can put it back in.